# How to find the speed of a bob when its wire has reduced its radius?

Tags: algebra-precalculus, physics, classical-mechanics

The problem is as follows:

> A brass sphere is hanging from a ceiling as it is seen in the figure
> from below. Assuming that at the position $A$ the speed is
> $3\frac{m}{s}$ the bob swings and hits a bolt located in point $B$. As
> a result the bob keeps swinging in the trajectory indicated by the
> dashed line.
>
> [image: Sketch of the problem]
>
> Using this information find the speed of the bob when it passes
> through point $C$. You may assume that the acceleration due gravity is
> $g=10\frac{m}{s^2}$.

The alternatives given in my book are as follows:

$\begin{array}{ll}
1.&\textrm{3.6 meters per second}\\
2.&\textrm{2.8 meters per second}\\
3.&\textrm{4.2 meters per second}\\
4.&\textrm{1.8 meters per second}\\
\end{array}$

So far what I've attempted to do is to use the conservation of mechanical energy on this system as follows:

Assuming that the moment when the bob is at $A$ it will have the same energy as when it passes below the point $B$. I'm assuming that the reference for the potential energy is just below point $B$. I mean where the bolt is put in the wall.

$E_{kA}+E_{uA}=E_{kB}$

Well after doing this I'm getting:

$\frac{1}{2}mv^2_{A}+mgR=\frac{1}{2}mv^2_{B}$

Cancelling the mass and replaing the known quantities I'm getting:

$v^2_{B}=9+8$

$v^{2}_{B}=17$

Now in this second segment I'm assuming that the energy on point $B$ will remain the same as when it passes through point $C$.

Therefore:

$\frac{1}{2}mv^2_{B}=\frac{1}{2}mv^2_{C}+mgR$

But since R=0.4 this will make that the speed on $C$ to be also 3 meters per second.

What could it be wrong in this analysis?. Did I overlooked something?. Can someone help me to spot what did I do wrong?.

The more I look into this question, I think that this may have to do to work with the tension of the wire.

I have not used the fact that of the angle which was given. Should this be used?.
If I were to use the angle initially I could calculate the initial tension of the wire. I mean on point $A$.

But this tension will not be the same when the bob passes through point $C$. Perhaps does it exist a way to find it?.

Can someone guide me here?. I feel lost. Please try to include a step by step explanation so I can understand.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The diagram is deceptive: the bob is $ \ 1.2 \cos 60º \ = 0.6 $ m. below the pivot, which is higher than point C at $ \ 0.8 $ m. below the pivot. [The bob goes from 0.6 m. to 0.4 m. above the lowest point of the pendulum swing.]  So the change in potential energy of the bob is
$ \ -0.2 mg \ $ from point A to point C .

The speed at point C  is then given by

$ \ \frac{1}{2} \ v^{2} \ = \  \frac{1}{2} · 3^{2}  \ + \ (0.6 - 0.4)  · g  \ $ ;

this does give one of the available choices for the result.

Concerning the tension in the wire, while it is true that $ \ T \ $ throughout the swing varies, this force is always perpendicular to the circular arc of the swing.  So in a simple pendulum, the tension does no work on the bob, and so does not enter into the kinetic energy - potential energy calculation.  The tension force only serves to control the *trajectory* of the bob.

Comment: Welcome to MathSE! I don't know if anybody mentioned to you this but I'd like to say that. By the way, thanks for your explanation. I totally overlooked that fact. As you mentioned the diagram is some deceptive. However there is an unattended question. The tension in the wire, is not constant. I mean the tension in point A is not the same when the bob passes through point C. Given this information, is it possible to find it?. I think it can as we know the $v_{C}$ then $T=\frac{mv^2}{R}$. Isn't it?.

Comment: Yes, with R = 1.2 m. from point A to point B , and R = 0.4 m. from B to C .  The height of the bob above the lowest point of the swing is  $ \ h \ = \ 1.2 · ( 1 - \cos \theta ) \ $ , with $ \ \theta \ $ being the angle of the pendulum off vertical during A to B , with 1.2 changed to 0,4 during B to C .  We would find $ \ v \ $ for the tension calculation from $ \ v^2 \ + \ 2gh \ = \ 3^2 \ + \ 1.2g \ $ .